# Invert colors on image on client browsers : what are my options?

Tags: browser, cross-browser

I'm working on a music website which displays waveforms for any given playing track. The waveforms have been generated in advance with the actual waveform being transparent and the area "around" the waveform being white. This allows me to easily set the actual waveform color using a background color behind the image. However, I need to convert the "area" around the waveform to black.

What are my options on this? This is how things have been going so far:

- I can't use a JS library for this, as I run into cross domain issues due to the fact that the waveforms are on a CDN on a different domain.
- It's going fine in Chrome using CSS `-webkit-filter: invert();
- I can't get `-moz-filter: invert(100%);` in FireFox to work. Neither does it work with SVG filters.
- Not sure what I'll do with MSIE.

Any advise appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If your waves are an image, I use the following CSS for Firefox (note: no -moz- filter).

```
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'>
        <filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\'
        values=\'-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter>
        </svg>#grayscale");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have strange color issue using Walter's answer (filter:...), you can add `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` to your filter

so Walter's answer becomes

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'>
    <filter id=\'grayscale\' color-interpolation-filters=\'sRGB\'>
    <feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter>
    </svg>#grayscale");
```

source: http://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/comment/69793#Comment_69793